# Django index page shows ViewDoesNotExist at / Could not import mysite.views.home. Parent module mysite.views does not exist

Tags: python, django

I am new to django..
When I was working before 2 days..it was working properly..
Now django index page shows ..

ViewDoesNotExist at /

Could not import mysite.views.home. Parent module mysite.views does not exist.
my url.py contain

```
 url(r'^$', 'mysite.views.home', name='home'),
```

please help me.
Where I did mistake??

Comment: Is mysite actually an application? have you included it in the INSTALLED_APPS section of your settings?

Comment: Could you post your directory structure and settings

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seems like a mistake in your views.py. Could you add the home view code?

Comment: my home folder does not contain a view.py page.It contains only setting.py,init.py,urls.py,wsgi.py –

Comment: My other apps are working fine...the problem is only with index page and admin page??I was just following django documentation given in their site..it was working fine..

Comment: Comments are where additional information requests belong

Answer (score 0):

Is the views.py that you are referring to in the project root? Error message says it can't find that file so check the path. If you moved the home view into an app folder, make sure you configured your settings file to include the app and point to the app folder as app_folder.views.home

Comment: my home folder does not contain a view.py page.It contains only setting.py,__init__.py,urls.py,wsgi.py

Comment: That's your problem, you have it pointing to my site(home folder).views(.py).home change the import to be the folder in the root directory that contains the views.py